# return response from scrapy in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape certain websites in python. When the response is downloaded, I want to pass this response to the main program

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'piracy'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        self.start_urls = kwargs.get('url_to_scrap')
        self.returndict = kwargs.get('returndict')

    def parse(self, response):
        print "Getting Text From {}".format(response.url)
        #return the_html_page

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

crawler = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

crawler.crawl(QuotesSpider, url_to_scrap=['https://google.com'])

te = Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()

# here I should get page response
# print the_html_page
```

I need to get the returned response after the reactor has run in the thread for post processing.

Comment: set a global var before the class and and assign him response inside parse

Comment: Or, alternatively, if memory is a potential issue, configure the spider to write to a file and later read from that file.

Comment: Can u elaborate your problem properly?!